# Is decresing intersection of closure of connected set is connected?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the following set $$ \bigcap_{t \in \Bbb R^+ \cup \{0\}} \bar{A_t}$$ where $A_t$'s are connected and decreasing. Note that it is an uncountable intersection. Is it true that the intersection is also connected ? If not what is the counterexample ?

Comment: Your notation suggests countability.  Instead of $t\ge0$,  for an uncountable intersection, use something like $i\in I$  where I is some arbitrary index set

Comment: @Alan : Did that. What about the solution/hint ?

Comment: Pretty sure it's true, since closures are also connected, and you're decreasing, but couldn't prove it offhand.

Comment: Are the $A_t$ supposed to be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}^n$, or general topological spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the ambient space is $\mathbb{R}$, then the intersection must be connected (unless you consider the empty set disconnected), since the connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are precisely the [possibly empty or degenerate] intervals, and a nested intersection of intervals is an interval [possibly degenerate or empty].

Otherwise, consider

$$A_t = \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \lvert y\rvert \geqslant 1 \lor x \geqslant t \right\}.$$

Comment: Good counterexample.